# Kendo datasource schema with multiple json elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I would like to pass my complete json element through the data schema and use it within the fetch function of the datasource.  I´ve been going through the documentation from Telerik and can not find examples that fit my needs, perhaps I´m thinking this usage wrong.  Is this in fact possible with the Kendo datasource?

**### DerpController ###**

```
public ActionResult GetDerps(string derpNumber)
{
    List<Derp> derps = _getDerps();
    List<Derpina> derpinas = _getDerpinas();
    var generic = new {Derps = derps, Derpinas = derpinas};
    return Json(generic);
}
```

**### jQuery ###**

```
//These are populated correctly through the schema but I would like to skip using 
//these variables and pass the elements with the data schema (if possible)
var derps;
var derpinas;

var systDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'Derp/GetDerps/',
            data: {
                derpNumber: derpNumber
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
            //This works fine if I use the variables above
            derps= response.Derps;
            derpinas= response.Derpinas;
            return response;
        }
    }
});

systDataSource.fetch(function () {
    var data = this.data();
    //I would like to be able to do something like this
    var theDerps = data.derps;

    //stuff abbreviated
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use it only once or each time that you re-read from the datasource? I recommend using [```

Comment: I would like to use it every time I read from the datasource.  When you say [''' what is that?  :)

Comment: Sorry, bad formatting of the link. I mean: using [`requestEnd`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd) event. This is triggered each time the DataSource finished loading data.